# discharging of a battery

Tags: electric-current

When current is being drawn from a battery then it is being discharged?Is that true ?Because this statement was written on my book ,when I researched about it I found an article in which was written that in ,lithium iodine battery when current is drawn then its discharging is reduced ,I am little confused ,can anyone help me out !

Answer (score 0):

I will assume we are dealing here with rechargeable batteries.

When current is being withdrawn from a fully-charged battery, that battery is being slowly discharged. It is called "*discharged*" when it is electrochemically exhausted and can furnish no more current.

Lithium ion batteries are no different in this regard. However, because of the peculiarities of the electrochemistry occurring inside them, if they are allowed to discharge completely- drained all the way down to zero current- then their capacity to store a full charge next time is reduced: in other words, they suffer permanent damage if run all the way down to zero current. For this reason, lithium ion batteries must be disconnected and recharged prior to hitting the completely exhausted state.

I think this effect may be what the article was referencing.